# Convert Zapier inputData from decimal to hex

Tags: javascript, hex, zapier

I have been trying for some time now to get Zapier to convert `inputData` from PayPal from `decimal` to `hex`. It pulls the information, but the output remains `decimal`.

```
return {
  steam: Number(inputData.rawNumber.toString(16))
};
```

`InputData.rawNumber` is pulling a user entered number from a PayPal sale.

If I change `inputData.rawNumber` to a number rather than pulling the data, the code works fine and the output returns as `hex`.

I have also tried this format with the same result. The data was called `steam` here rather than `rawNumber`.

```
var steamid = inputData.steam; 
var result = steamid.toString(16); 
output = {steamhex: result};
```

Could you please advise me on the right option?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Number(inputData.rawNumber.toString(16))` ? This will fail for eg. `rawNumber=255` and what should it be useful for?

Comment: The number is a decimal steam key. It needs to be converted into hex format for it's intended purpose. I want to automate this rather than have the end-user convert it.

Comment: can you give an example of desired input/output and the actual input/output you're seeing now? it looks like it should work

Comment: Yes it should that is my issue. I’m not sure if it is the limitations of zapier or not. 

Example: 100988765 is a test number which zapier is pulling from a mock PayPal sale using inputData. It pulls the number fine but the output even after the code has run will still be 100988765. 

If you replace inputData with 100988765 the script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your problem is that `inputData.rawNumber` is already a string. Resulting in this:

```js
'100988765'.toString(16) // => "100988765"
```

Instead, parse it into a number first:

```js
const steamIdAsNum = parseInt(inputData.steam, 10)
return {steamhex: steamIdAsNum.toString(16)}
```

Comment: Separately, I'd love to hear more about what you're doing with this functionality! I was the one who made the [Steam integration](https://zapier.com/apps/steam/integrations) and love seeing what folks are doing with zapier and gaming